# Get string-length for a given font and rect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, core-graphics

I have a custom `UIView` class, and in the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` I want to draw some text. However I want the text block to be limited to a maximum width of 84px at a system font size of 12. If the text exceeds this width, I want to cut it and make the last 3 character to be "...".

Example:

```
"This is some text"    // length okay
"Information co..."    // length truncated
```

I know that I can calculate the width of a string with a given font through `NSString`'s `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font`, but how can I get the maximum string length for 84px width?

Comment: The problem is there are not many (if any) monospaced fonts on iOS. so you could probably fit let's say 10 'i' characters in the same width as 6 'X' characters

Comment: [This blog](http://joshjustice.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/monospace-fonts-on-ios/) even says that monospaced fonts are not really monospaced in iOS :/ - so you'll really be better of with using `sizeWithFont:` for every string you want to use

Comment: There must be a way. `UILabel` is doing it. I Could do some form of binary-search for the correct length, retrying in a loop until the length fits, but that seems ugly to me ...

Comment: Yes, i was talking about getting the maximum number of characters for certain width - this is possible only with a real (concrete) string - eg. to check wheather it fits or not. `drawAtPoint: forWidth: withFont: does exactly that`. Glad you solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am understanding your situation correctly, then you should use the method
`- (CGSize)drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)point forWidth:(CGFloat)width withFont:(UIFont *)font lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode` and use UILineBreakModeTailTruncation for the line break mode.

Comment: Well that was incredibly easy. Thanks!

Comment: `drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:lineBreakMode:` is deprecated in iOS 7.0. "Use `drawInRect:withAttributes:` instead." @iJordan do you know how to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know the maximum number of characters allowed for a certain width and font. Unfortunately that's impossible to know, since there are many different character sizes ('m' is wider than 'l').

What you can do is call:

```
[@"Your text here" sizeWithFont:yourFont minFontSize:smallestFontSizeYouWillAccept actualFontSize:&pointerToYourFontSizeFloatValue forWidth:yourWidthConstraint lineBreakMode:yourLineBreakMode];
```

This will alter your fontSize float value (since you passed the pointer to it) and it will now be the biggest font size that you can use without having the line break. With the float you gave it, you can create a new font and set the size to your float.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This method will be helpful in your case:
`- (CGSize)drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)point forWidth:(CGFloat)width withFont:(UIFont *)font lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode`

Its a reliable clue for your case